# How to untrack files (git and git GUI)

Tags: git, git-gui

I am using git GUI (together with Git bash). Now, I know if I want to ignore files for git I have to put them in a .gitignore file.

1)I have come to know that git in windows does not create a .gitignore file for you and you have to create it yourself. Also git GUI won't do that. Is this correct?

Now my special situation:

I made a mistake in the beginning of managing this project and together with my .c and .h files I also tracked another file (let's call it "shouldnottrack.file"). This file is generated by the build process, so in principle should not be tracked.

But I did it and it was included in the commits (staged, commited etc).

Now, I want to **untrack** this file.

I have done it temporalily by doing `git checkout -- shouldnottrack.file` but this works only once

2. How can I untrack this file? (GUI, command, any method ok)
3. If I include this file in the .gitignore file, will git untrack it automatically?

Answer (score 43):

You have to add it to `.gitignore` **and** remove it from the git repository so that it stop to track it.

`.gitignore` has no effects on file already tracked.

You have 2 possibilities depending if you still want to keep your files in the working directory or not:

- **If you want to delete the files in your working directory**, do `git rm`.
- **If you want to keep them** but just stop to track them, do `git rm --cached`.

Then, commit this file deletion.

Comment: won't using 'git rm' delete the file? I want to keep the file (not delete it) , just untracked.

Comment: Why is it a problem because you will regenerate it if that 's a build result? Anyway, that should be' git rm --cached'

Comment: I see, so next time when I build (and get the file) this will be untracked? (then I will put it in the ignorelist)

Comment: Ignore list is just used for untracked file so you could do it when you want (right now!) but you will see its effect just once the file has been untracked (once you commited its deletion)

Comment: I found the answer in a book on Git. The way to do it is 1) git rm --cached shouldnottrack.file , include it in the .gitignore and then commit . In that way the file is untracked.  (I don't know if I should edit your reply to include that- sorrry)

Comment: That's what I told you to do in my 2nd comment ;-)

Comment: haha! now I see it! I must be lacking of coffee ;P Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your first question as I exclusively use the Git CLI however for your second question try this:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Replacing PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE with the actual file name you want to scrub from the history. You should see something along the lines of:

```
Rewrite 48dc599c80e20527ed902928085e7861e6b3cbe6 (266/266)
Ref refs/heads/master was rewritten
```

If it was successful - After this if you have already pushed to your remote you will need to do a `git push --force` to overwrite it. Security settings on the branch may deny the push.

Finally, for your last question, to prevent this happening again add the file in question to your .gitignore file and git will prevent any tracking from occurring.

The above answer will work however I strongly suggest this approach if the data was sensitive - ie passwords, ssh keys etc as the files will still be in history.

You can read more here https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/ and here https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/.