# PowerShell, posh-git is reporting .gitignore'd folders as being part of the repo

Tags: git, powershell, .git-folder

I have a git project spawns a lot of nested sub-folders beside the project (I need the project to be at the root of this folder tree for various reasons). All of these subfolders are in my `.gitignore` so *should* have no relationship to my git project. However, when I am in any of those `.gitignore`'d subfolders of my main project, when I do a `dir` when the `posh-git` module is imported, it reports that I am in a git project, and states the number of uncommitted changes in my root project (I'm not talking about being in the `.git` folder, just normal folders that are within the repo folder, but are also in the `.gitignore`). I would like this subfolder to not be regarded as part of my git project. Is `git-posh` reporting this wrongly? i.e. should a subfolder of a git project *even if it is in `.gitignore`* be regarded as part of the project?

Comment: Files in '.gitconfig' are not necessary ignored *if they are tracked by git i.e. you have committed them before ignoring them*. So, try to stop tracking them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41051500/717372

Comment: You need to be very specific when setting up your .gitignore. Everything not specified in .gitignore is part of the repo.