# How can I ignore files in my git repository already having declared in the .gitIngore?

Tags: .net, git

I have a Git repository with several projects created with .NET, with a layered structure where each layer is stored in sub folders, but when I compile my complete solution, many modified files appear in the repository that should be ignored.

Such as the folder .vs/, obj/, bin/, among others.

[image]

My git ignore file is in the solution root folder.

[image]

Inside the file I have the configurations that I used in old projects, the difference that I have is that this solution consists of several solutions saved in sub folders.

[image]

Comment: It’s clearer if you just copy the contents of your `.gitignore` into a codeblock (instead of the image).

Comment: I think I tend to use `git ls-files` when I want to check if files which I _think_ are ignored really are.

Comment: If you have files already pushed to remote, adding to `.gitignore` will not work straight away. First you need to delete files from remote and then add to `.gitignore`. (Not sure if this is the case here but keep in mind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.gitignore` rules applies only for not tracked files.

So if you want to ignore all these files, you have to untracked them and commit this "deletion":

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41051500/717372